# PDO FullText Search

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having a problem in writing the query for a fulltext search. Here is my code:

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE MATCH (color) AGAINST (:term IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I am getting no result when executing that query, but when I hardcoded the term like this,

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE MATCH (color) AGAINST ('yellow' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I get some results. I guess I need the colon part to be rewritten with some concatenations. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you  binding a value to `:term`

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE MATCH (color) AGAINST (:term IN BOOLEAN MODE));
$stmt->bindValue(":term", "yellow");
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: yellow ain't constant

Comment: `$stmt->bindValue(":term", $variable);`

Answer (score 0):

Nope, semicolons don't need no concatenations.
You just need to test your prepared statement version on the **exactly the same table** against which you run your raw query.